# What is the right form? Causative

Tags: grammar

- *You will probably get mugged if walk through that part of town*

or

- *You will probably get yourself mugged if walk through that part of town.*

Can I use "have" instead of "get"?

Comment: “. . . if you walk” is what you need.

Comment: After adding 'you' after 'if' as @Xanne prompts, either is acceptable, though the second is in a pretty informal style (in the UK, the first is also informal; 'be mugged' is less colloquial). 'Have yourself mugged' means you arranged it rather than risked it.

Comment: The _get_ Passive is not a causative; it's normally inchoative. It's just an alternative passive construction that  uses inchoative _get_ instead of stative _be_ as its auxiliary verb. The second sentence, with a reflexive, is causative, like _I got my tires rotated_, for instance. but the _get_ Passive is not a causative. And, no, you can't use _have_ instead of _get_.

Answer (score 0):

"*You will probably have mugged if you walk through that part of town.*" Is meaningful but doesn't mean "*You will probably get mugged if you walk through that part of town.*" On the contrary it says that, if you walk through that part of town, you have probably mugged someone in the past. It is the same construction as "*You will probably have passed the Town Hall if you walk through that part of town.*" (Because you probably had to go past the Town Hall to get to that part of town). The reason for this is that "have mugged" is a compound verb and, without an object, takes 'you' as its subject. That is 'you' did the mugging of an unspecified person.

"*You will probably have yourself mugged if you walk through that part of town.*", on the other hand, does mean pretty much the same as "*You will probably get yourself mugged if you walk through that part of town.*" The reason is that the reflexive form 'yourself' makes you the object of whatever verb is used and its presence between 'have' and 'mugged' means that the compound verb 'have mugged' is not formed.

Having said that "*have yourself mugged*" is still a bit strange because it could be taken to mean that you had arranged for someone to mug you. It is the same form as "*You will probably have yourself taken to the airport in a taxi*" and says that you will probably have arranged to have a service done for you.

Comment: get something done/ have something done - In most situations these are interchangeable. However, when we say, "have someone/something do..." it's equivalent cannot be 'get someone/something do...(?), but "Get someone TO do... In other words, 'Have him do it' becomes 'Get him TO do it.'

Comment: @RamPillai That's very true.